# setAttributes method of KnpMenuBundle doesn't work

Tags: symfony, twig, knpmenubundle

I'm using `KnpMenuBundle` in my Symfony2 application.
I'm trying to set the menu `class` attribute using `setAttributes` of `FactoryInterface` of `KnpMenuBundle` like this:

```
    $menu = $factory->createItem('root');
    $menu->setAttribute('class' , 'sf-menu');
```

But this doesn't work! and the resulting markup with or without the `setAttribute` line is:

```
<ul>
    <li class="first">
     ...
</ul>
```

while I expect to have `<ul class='sf-menu'>`

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to give a class to **li** elements, you have to set it this way:

```
$menu->addChild('Label', [
    ...
    'attributes' => ['class' => 'sf-menu'],
]);
```

If you want to give a class to your **ul** element:

```
$menu = $this->factory->createItem('root');
$menu->setChildrenAttribute('class', 'sf-menu');
```